# Springboot : delete all cookies for a specific domain

Tags: java, spring-boot, cookies

I am deleting cookies one by one by manually providing cookie field names for specific domain by using below code in spring boot.

```
ResponseCookie rs = ResponseCookie.from("<cookie field key>",null).domain("abc.com").maxAge(0).path("/").build();
headers.add(HttpHeaders.SET_COOKIE,rs.toString());
```

But I want to delete all the cookies for a specific domain without providing cookie field names.

Comment: did you check my answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with

```
public void deleteCookiesFromDomain(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, String domain) {
    Arrays.stream(request.getCookies()).filter(cookie -> cookie.getDomain().equals(domain)).forEach(cookie -> {
        cookie.setMaxAge(0);
        cookie.setPath("/");
        response.addCookie(cookie);
    });
```

`HttpServletRequest` and `HttpServletResponse` could be injected in your controller from Spring if requested.